# Why Fault pin of IR2136 gate driver is getting low at high voltage?

Tags: noise, gate-driving, igbt, vfd

I am implementing a variable frequency drive for a three-phase induction motor.  I used IGBT module fs25r12w1t4 with gate driver ( three phase, six Channels IR2136). When I increase the voltage, the fault pin receives a noise or anyway it goes to zero. The controller reads it as zero. so Fault interrupts become active as it considered that the fault has occurred.

Then I checked the fault pin of IR2136 through Oscilloscope, it goes to low at 170 V. It remains active below the voltage level of 170V.
please, can you tell me what may the issue with the gate driver IR2136? why it goes to low at high voltage.
This problem happens at high voltage.

Comment: Show schematic. Show oscillograms.

Comment: From the datasheet: "An open-drain FAULT signal is provided to indicate that an overcurrent or undervoltage shutdown has occurred." So a good guess would be that either an over-current or under-voltage condition has occurred, this results in the fault pin being pulled low.